# Passar informações atualizadas de subreport para report pai

Tags: java, ireport, jasper-reports

Estou fazendo um relatório que contem todos prestadores de serviço, e possui a seguinte hierarquia: Cidade -> Especialidade -> Prestador.

No ireport ficou o relatório principal que contem um subreport de cidade, dentro do subreport de cidade tem  um subreport de especialidades e dentro do especialidades tem um subreport de todos prestadores de serviço.

Meu problema é no report principal que precisa que cada página tenha o  nome da cidade e na lateral o nome da especialidade.
Passar informações do subreport para o relatório principal eu consigo, através de uma variável, só não consigo colocar no header pois ele é compilado antes da banda que está o subreport de cidades, e quando coloco em outra banda ele só mostra o nome da ultima cidade.
E colocar também o nome da especialidade na lateral do mesmo modo do nome da cidade.

O relatório tem um padrão a ser seguido, que é de acordo com um exemplo que eu fiz a seguir.
[Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFm9m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio não ser necessário criar um relatório com três níveis. Você pode resolver isso criando uma query que faça o join das três tabelas e criar dois grupos, um para cidade e outro para especialidade.

Como não conheço seu modelo, vou rascunhar um exemplo de query:

```sql
select c.nome as nome_cidade, e.titulo as titulo_especialidade,
       p.codigo as id_prestador, p.nome as nome_prestador, p.info as info_prestador
  from cidade c
  join especialidade e
       on e.codigo_cidade = c.codigo
  join prestador p
       on p.codigo_cidade = c.codigo
       and p.codigo_especialidade = e.codigo
  order by c.nome, e.titulo, p.nome
```

Seguindo esse exemplo, agora basta criar grupos no iReport (não na query), a saber, um grupo pelo valor de `$F{nome_cidade}` e outro por `$P{titulo_especialidade}`.

Dessa forma, você não vai precisar de nenhum subrelatório e terá todos os dados à disposição para exibir no cabeçalho dos grupos e também na lateral.

Comment: Mas nesse caso ao invés de passar a lista, passaria o SQL para o ireport executar? Se for passar, vou ter que executar muitas validações que deixei a cargo do java fazer.

Comment: @adelmo00 Você está usando JPA? Não está claro na sua pergunta. Em todo caso, você tem duas alternativas: mudar para SQL ou criar uma lista única que contenha os dados das 3 entidades (repetindo a cidade e a especialidade para cada prestador).

Comment: Não estou usando JPA. O administrador do banco me passou a Query que lista as informações, executo essa query pelo JDBC separo em listas e envio para o jasper montar o relatorio. Vou fazer do jeito que você disse passando a Query direto para o jasper e montar os agrupamentos nele.

Comment: @adelmo00 Certo, nesse caso seria melhor passar a query para o relatório.